# Bracket matching using tree structure in ruby

Tags: ruby, binary-tree, brackets

Given a string that contains only characters from the set `{}[]()` I want to generate a tree structure that starts with an opening bracket -- `{[(` -- and adds a node if the next character is another opening bracket.  If the next character is a closing bracket that matches the current node value, I want the current node eliminated.  If the next character is a closing bracket that does not match the current node, then it should return an error.
For example, given the string `"{[()]}"` the code would do something like:

```
    {
   /
  [
 /
(
```

Then the next character is the closing bracket that matches the current (most recently inserted) node, so it should delete that node.

```
    {
   /
  [
```

and then

```
{
```

and finally

```
nil
```

The following code almost works, but because it traverses the tree top to bottom, it will match brackets that have an unclosed bracket between them, such as "{[(]}".  I'm keeping track of height b/c I feel like I should be able to use that to jump to the last node, but not sure how.

```
module BracketTree
  class Node
    attr_accessor :key, :left, :right

    BRACKETS = {"{" => "}",
                "[" => "]",
                "(" => ")"
                }

    def initialize(key)
      @key = key
      @left = nil
      @right = nil
    end

    def height
      @height = 1
      left = @left
      while !left.nil?
        left = left.left
        @height += 1
      end
      @height
    end

    def insert(new_key)
      if @key.nil?
        @key = new_key
      elsif BRACKETS[new_key]
        if @left.nil?
          @left = Node.new(new_key)
        else
          @left.insert(new_key)
        end
      elsif @left.nil? && BRACKETS[@key] == new_key
        @key = nil
      elsif BRACKETS[@left.key] == new_key
        @left = nil
      else
        left = @left
        while !left.nil?
          if BRACKETS[left.key] == new_key
            left.key = nil
            break
          else
            left = left.left
          end
        end
        if left.nil?
          raise "unmatched bracket or non bracket char"
        else
          left.right
        end
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: To understand this question one must read through the code (or at least I would have to do so). That should not be necessary, and given the amount of code, most readers would not be prepared to do that. You need to define what the tree looks like and what you mean by " ..it should delete the node...". A small example, including the desired return value, would be especially useful,

Comment: @CarySwoveland Is that any better?

Comment: Is this not using a stack for learning purposes or other restrictions? Doing this as a tree, you could keep track of what your current leaf node is, so you can insert easily, but then to delete, I believe you'd have to traverse through and find the current leafs parent and remove the pointer to the leaf and then set your leaf to the old leafs parent.

Comment: Yes, not using a stack simply for learning purposes.

Comment: The question is more clear, but I still don't understand the objective. You are given a string of arbitrary length, each character of which is one of the two (left and right) *brace markers", `"{}"`, *bracket markers*, `"[]"` or *parentheses markers*, `"()"`. I understand the rules for adding "nodes" and deleting matching pairs of markers that are separated by one node. What is the desired return value ("output") for each of the following strings: `"{[()]}"`,  `"{[()}"`,  `"{[(})]}"` `"(((("`? (You said it is `nil` for  `"{[()]}".)

Comment: Desired output would be: nil or "", "[", "}", "((((" for your examples.

Comment: Thank you, Matthew. In my answer below I modified the return values you suggest to provide additional information when the markers are not balanced. Tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a stack should be used here.

**Code**

```
MATCH_UP = { "}"=>"{", "]"=>"[", ")"=>"(" }
LT_MARKERS = MATCH_UP.values #=> ["{", "[", "("]

def parse_markers(str)
  str.each_char.with_index.with_object([]) do |(marker, i), stack|
    if LT_MARKERS.include?(marker)
      stack << marker
    elsif MATCH_UP[marker] == stack.last
      stack.pop
    else
      return [stack.join, i]
    end
  end.join
end
```

There are three possible outcomes.

- If `str` has balanced markers, the method returns `""`.
- If all characters of `str` are mutually consistent but the stack is not empty after all characters have been examined (for example, `"((("`, would terminate with `stack.join #=> "(0(0("`), `stack.join` is returned (signifying that `str` is unbalanced).
- Otherwise the array `[stack.join, off]` is returned, where `stack` is the stack at the time the determination was made that the markers are not balanced because the character `str[off]` was found to be inconsistent with the stack.

**Examples**

```
parse_markers("{[()]}")    #=> ""           (balanced)
parse_markers("{[()}")     #=> ["{[", 4]
parse_markers("{[(})]}")   #=> ["{[(", 3]
parse_markers("((((")      #=> "(((("    (consistent but not balanced) 
parse_markers("{[]}((]()") #=> ["((", 6]
parse_markers("")          #=> ""           (balanced)
parse_markers("}[()]{")    #=> ["", 0]
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `NODE`, is that just a spacer for the output (you could accomplish that with `join("0")`)? Also, `RT_MARKERS` isn't used anywhere and can probably be removed

Comment: @SimpleLime, thanks for the mention of `RT_MARKERS`. I've now removed that. I'm falling asleep so will get back to you tomorrow about `NODE`,  That's an interesting idea about `join("0")`. I think that would mean `pop(1)` rather than `pop(2)`, but zzzzzzzzzzz.

Comment: Yes, I understand a stack is the more obvious way to approach this problem.  In fact, I have already solved the problem using a stack approach (see [here](http://exercism.io/submissions/832ddfcdaeb64efe9024858fd3c16cbe)).  I think if I'm going to make a tree work, I'll just have to store all the characters in the tree and then have a method to check if each node is balanced.  Ideally I'll also come up with a way to invert the tree such that it works in a LIFO manner.

Comment: I see from the code at your link that the problem is merely to determine if a sequence of markers is balanced, with the stipulation that a tree data structure be employed in the solution. The question would have been clearer if you had said that at the outset. (btw, the downvote is not mine.) @SimpleLime, I don't think anything more need be said about `NODE`, except, yes, it must go.

Comment: I don't like the term 'balanced' for this because "{[}]" is balanced but not valid.  That's why I phrased the question the way I did.  I also phrased it the way I did because I was not trying to solve the bracket parsing problem so much as learn about tree structures.

Comment: I've often seen "balanced" defined as I've used it. [Here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets) is an example. It's very convenient having a term for that; otherwise many careful words would be needed to describe a sequence with the required properties. You and the author at the link I gave used the term "bracket" to include parentheses, braces and brackets, which is a bit circular. I'd prefer a term other than "bracket" to refer to all three (or to `[` and `]`), but I'm not losing any sleep over it.